# String.IndexOf() returns unexpected value - cannot extract substring between two search strings

Tags: html, powershell, substring, string-parsing

*Script to manipulate some proper names in a web story to help my reading tool pronounce them correctly.*

I get the content of a webpage via

```
$webpage = (Invoke-WebRequest -URI 'https://wanderinginn.com/2018/03/20/4-20-e/').Content
```

This $webpage should be of type String.

Now

```
$webpage.IndexOf('<div class="entry-content">')
```

returns correct value, yet

```
$webpage.IndexOf("Previous Chapter")
```

returns unexpected value and I need some explanation why or how I can find the error myself.

*In theory it should cut the "body" of the page run it through a list of proper nouns I want to Replace and push this into a htm-file.
It all works, but the value of IndexOf("Prev...") does not.*

Edit:
After invoke-webrequest I can

```
Set-Clipboard $webrequest
```

and post this in notepad++, there I can find both 'div class="entry-content"' and 'Previous Chapter'.
If I do something like

```
Set-Clipboard $webpage.substring(
     $webpage.IndexOf('<div class="entry-content">'),
     $webpage.IndexOf('PreviousChapter')
   )
```

**I would expect Powershell to correctly determine both first instances of those strings and cut between.** Therefore my clipboard should now have my desired content, yet the string goes further than the first occurrence.

Comment: What unexpected value you get? What value you expect instead and why?

Comment: This works for me just fine `(Invoke-WebRequest -URI 'https://wanderinginn.com/2018/03/20/4-20-e/').Content.indexof('Previous Chapter')` which gets me 87859. What is wrong with that? Are you expecting a line number as supposed to a character number?

Comment: `IndexOf()` simply returns the integer index of the requested string. You need to use that information to cut out what you need.

Comment: the `.SubString()` method uses `StartIndex` alone OR `StartIndex`, Length`. you are giving it two start index numbers. ///// you need to set the 2nd number to the _difference between the two index values_. [*grin*]

Comment: Oh man, I'm a putz. Thank you! I think I made it harder for myself because notepad++'s find always showed different character counts vs powershell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- You had a **misconception about how [`String.Substring()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_System_Int32_) works**: the second argument must be the *length* of the substring to extract, not the end *index* (character position) - see below.
- As an **alternative**, you can use a more concise (albeit more complex) ***regex* operation with 
  `-replace`** to extract the substring of interest in a single operation - see below.
- Overall, it's **better to use an *HTML parser*** to extract the desired information, because string processing is *brittle* (HTML allows variations in whitespace, quoting style, ...).

---

As [Lee_Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) points out, you had a **misconception about how the [`String.Substring()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_System_Int32_) works**: its arguments are:

- a ***starting index*** (`0`-based character position),
- from which a substring of a given ***length*** should be returned.

Instead, you tried to pass another *index* as the *length* argument.

To fix this, you must ***subtract* the lower index from the higher one**, so as to obtain the length of the substring you want to extract:

A simplified example:

```
# Sample input from which to extract the substring 
#   '>>this up to here' 
# or, better,
#   'this up to here'.
$webpage = 'Return from >>this up to here<<'


# WRONG (your attempt): 
# *index* of 2nd substring is mistakenly used as the *length* of the
# substring to extract, which in this even *breaks*, because a length
# that exceeds the bounds of the string is specified.
$webpage.Substring(
  $webpage.IndexOf('>>'),
  $webpage.IndexOf('<<')
)

# OK, extracts '>>this up to here'
# The difference between the two indices is the correct length
# of the substring to extract.
$webpage.Substring(
  ($firstIndex = $webpage.IndexOf('>>')),
  $webpage.IndexOf('<<') - $firstIndex
)

# BETTER, extracts 'this up to here'
$startDelimiter = '>>'
$endDelimiter = '<<'
$webpage.Substring(
  ($firstIndex = $webpage.IndexOf($startDelimiter) + $startDelimiter.Length),
  $webpage.IndexOf($endDelimiter) - $firstIndex
)
```

**General caveats re `.Substring()`**:

In the following cases this .NET method throws an *exception*, which PowerShell surfaces as a *statement*-terminating error; that is, by default the statement *itself* is terminated, but execution *continues*:

- If you specify an index that is outside the bounds of the string (a `0`-based character position less than `0` or one greater than the length of the string):

  ```
    'abc'.Substring(4) # ERROR "startIndex cannot be larger than length of string"
  ```
- If you specify a length whose endpoint would fall outside the bounds of the string (if the index plus the length yields an index that is greater than the length of the string).

  ```
    'abc'.Substring(1, 3) # ERROR "Index and length must refer to a location within the string"
  ```

---

That said, **you could use a single *regex* ([regular expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions)) to extract the substring of interest**, via the [`-replace` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators#replacement-operator):

```
$webpage = 'Return from >>this up to here<<'

# Outputs 'this up to here'
$webpage -replace '^.*?>>(.*?)<<.*', '$1'
```

The key is to have the regex match the *entire string* and extract the substring of interest via a *capture group* (`(...)`) whose value (`$1`) can then be used as the replacement string, effectively returning just that.

<sup>For more information about `-replace`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375).</sup>

Note: **In your specific case** an additional tweak is needed, because you're dealing with a *multiline* string:

```
$webpage -replace '(?s).*?<div class="entry-content">(.*?)Previous Chapter.*', '$1'
```

- Inline option (`(?...)`) `s` ensures that metacharacter `.` also matches *newline* characters (so that `.*` matches *across lines*), which it doesn't by default.
- Note that you may have to apply *escaping* to the search strings to embed in the regex, if they happen to contain regex *metacharacters* (characters with special meaning in the context of a regex):

  - With embedded literal strings, `\`-escape characters as needed; e.g., escape `.txt` as `\.txt`
  - If a string to embed comes from a *variable*, apply `[regex]::Escape()` to its value first; e.g.:

    ```
        $var = '.txt'
        # [regex]::Escape() yields '\.txt', which ensures 
        # that '.txt' doesn't also match '_txt"
        'a_txt a.txt' -replace ('a' + [regex]::Escape($var)), 'a.csv'
    ```